# SQL trouble with dots in data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm setting up a PHP redirecter with SQL as the database. As the SQL entries are URLs the have dots "." within the sting like example.com.

Now, when i try to get the correspondand target URL SQL always return 0 rows. I checked several different data packs and always, when a URL conatins a dot the query goes wrong. Does anybody has an idea how to make the query possible or do I have to replace all dots with a different sign?

Sorry, I'm pretty new to Stackoverflow. Here is my query:

```
$url="example.com";
$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM links WHERE source='".$url."' AND active=1");
```

I'm getting back 0 rows, but the tested $url is existing for sure (copied from phpMyAdmin). It's an mySQL server on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Cheers,
JCK

Comment: Show us a query containing dots and the error you get

Comment: Post some code and you may get the help you need.

Comment: Is this mySQL or SQL server? It can not be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use a regular expression to match the URL? You didn't include the query...

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

The above would be a regular expression to match a URL including the https and double forward slash

Numbers, letters, dots, and hyphens are included here.

And in MySQL you could use this to match it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp